# Kinetic energy in translation and rotation based on frame of reference

Tags: kinematics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

How does translational kinetic energy of a system depend on frame of reference where as rotational kinetic energy does not depend on reference frame?

Answer (score 1):

Translational KE changes when viewed from a different translating frame of reference. Rotational KE changes when viewed from a different rotating frame of reference.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike translational velocity, which is relative in Newtonian mechanics, rotation velocity and translational acceleration are absolute in Newtonian inertial frames of reference.